# Unable to select profiles when creating online event registration

Tags: civievent, profile, joomla

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.17 and Joomla 3.6.5 and I am unable to select a profile when I turn on online registration for an event. The "include profile" drop down field is greyed out, and when I click it only "None Found" is listed.  However, if I click on the "preview" button, it displays the default "Your Registration Info" profile.  I can also click "create" and create a new one.  It saves to the profiles, but when I come back into the event and select online registration, the new profile no longer shows up in the "include profile" field.

This is true for any of the "include profile" fields on the online registration configuration page.

I can select a profile for a contribution page but just not events.

I went back to Test site that was running CiviCRM 4.5.4, and I could select profiles.  I upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.9, and I was no longer able to select the profiles.  Version 4.6.9 post upgrade notes indicated that there were changes for the event workflow templates.  Not sure if that is related.

I tried this on the CiviCRM Joomla demo site, currently running v4.6.18, and I could select profiles.  However, the major difference is that I have several of the CiviCRM extensions installed on my Test and Prod sites.

I see similar posts, but some answers discuss Wordpress and others indicate a fix back in v4.5.4.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can anyone direct me in things to check out?  Really in a bind here with a production site.

Answer (score 2):

Found answer from a [newer post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18386/127):

> After more investigation, the problem is solved using the fix from
>   agh1 (thanks to him by the way).
>
> It looks like a problem in the civicrm code using jquery.
>
> Here is the url of the fix. We tested it and it works.
>
> https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10152
>
> I hope this will be in the next civicrm release code.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I've added the link to the other post.