# Profiles list not showing in dropdown list in Online Registration tab of Configure Event

Tags: civievent, profile, joomla

When we configure a new event, we add a profile (create) that has fields selected from the Individual list of fields. We give the profile a name, save it.

In the Include Profile (top of page) dropdown list, we can see the name of the profile and everything is OK.

We save the event and want to edit it again and go back to the Online Registration tab.

Now we don't see the name of the profile linked to this event. We can click on the dropdown list and there is nothing in it. If we click preview on the right, we can see the profile and the fields. We can also edit it.

We use civicrm 4.7.18 with Joomla 3.6.5.

Anyone knows why we would have this behavior.

The reason it is a problem is that we can't create an event and use a previous profile so we have to create a new one each time which is time consuming. A save as in the profile creation or edit there would help.

It looks like civicrm 4.7.18 has completely changed the tables linked to profiles and event management.

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation, the problem is solved using the fix from agh1 (thanks to him by the way).

It looks like a problem in the civicrm code using jquery.

Here is the url of the fix. We tested it and it works.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10152

I hope this will be in the next civicrm release code.